# How to know if the optimization problem is infeasible or not? Pyomo Warning: Problem may be infeasible

Tags: pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

Pyomo can find a solution, but it gives this warning: 
WARNING: Loading a SolverResults object with a warning status into
    model=(SecondCD);
        message from solver=Ipopt 3.11.1\x3a Converged to a locally infeasible point. Problem may be infeasible.

How do I know if the problem is infeasible or not?

this pyomo model optimizes a farm's decision of inputs allocation.

```
model.Crops = Set() # set Crops := cereal rapes maize ;
model.Inputs = Set() # set Inputs := land labor capital fertilizer;
model.b = Param(model.Inputs) # Parameters in CD production function
```

```
model.x = Var(model.Crops, model.Inputs, initialize = 100, within=NonNegativeReals)
```

```
def production_function(model, i): 
        return prod(model.x[i,j]**model.b[j] for j in model.Inputs)
model.Q = Expression(model.Crops, rule=production_function)
```

...

```
instance = model.create_instance(data="SecondCD.dat")
opt = SolverFactory("ipopt")
opt.options["tol"] = 1E-64
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True) # solves and updates instance 
instance.display()
```

if I set b >=1, (e.g.: param b := land 1 labor 1 capital 1 fertilizer 1),
pyomo can find optimal solution;

but if i set b < 1, (e.g.: param b := land 0.1 labor 0.1 capital 0.1 fertilizer 0.1), and set opt.options["tol"] = 1E-64, pyomo can find a solution, but gives that warning.

I expect an optimal solution, but the actual result gives the warning mentioned above.

Comment: Can you show the Ipopt log? For (non-convex) NLPs, it is not easy to prove the problem is infeasible. You can try multiple starting points (multi-start). If the problem is not large, you may be able to use a global NLP solver. Sometimes we can use a simpler, auxiliary model to find feasible solutions quicker or prove infeasibility (e.g. if the problem is infeasible in the linear constraints only, you have a proof).

Comment: where can I see ipopt log?

Comment: @LinmeiShang This is the print you get in your console using `tee=True`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56635422/4629624 (a recent answer I gave, still fresh in my mind), it should be the same for Ipopt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message you get (`message from solver=Ipopt 3.11.1\x3a Converged to a locally infeasible point. Problem may be infeasible.`) doesn't mean that the problem is necessarilly infeasible. A non-linear solver will typically give you a local optimum, and the path to get to the solution is a very important part of finding a "better" local optimum. When you tried with another point, you found a feasible solution, and that is the proof that your problem is feasible.

Now, in finding the global optimum instead of a local optimum, this is a little bit harder. One way to find out is to check if your problem is convex. If it is, it means that there will only be one local optimum, and that this local optimum is the global optimum. This can be done mathematically. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1707213/470821 and http://www.princeton.edu/~amirali/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec7_gh.pdf from a quick Google search). If you found that your problem is not convex, then you can try to prove that there are few local optimums and that they can be found easily with good starting points. Finally, if this can't be done, you should consider more advanced techniques, all with their pros and cons. For example, you can try to generate a set of starting solutions to make sure that you cover the whole feasible domain of your problem. Another one would be to use meta-heuristics methods to help you find a better starting solution.

Also, I am sure that Ipopt have some tools to help tackling this problem of finding a good starting solution that improves the resulting local optimum.

Comment: thanks a lot!  model.b is a parameter here, not a variable. Varying the value of a parameter means the objective function is also varying, thus problems are also changing. Maybe when model.b >=1, the problem is feasible; but when model.b <1, the problem is not feasiable anymore. But from your answer, I understood that this warning is caused by the initial value of a variable. If I find a good starting point, this warning might disappear. Right?

Comment: If you find a good starting point for your variables, yes it should be. I tend to say that non-linear optimization is like making a blind man try to find the highest point on an island. If you make him start closer to the wrong mountain, he might climb on the smallest mountain and conclude it is the highest point of the island, when in reality, it is not. And if you make him start in the middle of the sea, he will believe that no mountain exist. I think that the warning comes from the solver when trying to launch the problem with an unfeasible solution, or by "starting in the sea".

Comment: If you start from a solution that is known to be feasible, the solver will try to find the next best point until it reaches a constraint. Then, it will change direction to make sure it continues to find the next best solution, but without crossing the constraint. See the constraint as a fence for the blind man. Maybe the highest point is behind the fence, but at least, if the land keeps going up around the fence, the blind man will still follow the path arround the fence until it stops going up.

Comment: However, the global maximum might be on the other side of the island, and that is something you might want to check. And testing if your model is convex is a good way to check if there is only one "mountain" or global optimum.

Comment: An infeasible point is not a local optimum. But it is true that if an NLP solver is not able to find a feasible point, this is not necessarily an indication that a feasible point does not exist. (Well, unless the problem is convex). There is a difference between an infeasible point and an infeasible problem.

Comment: It is very strange: I converted the model from an abstract model to a concrete model. The concrete model can find an optimal solution, while the abstract model always encounters problems.  Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Indeed it is very strange. It is probably linked. Maybe you want to edit your question with this information, and how your abstract model was converted to a concrete model. Is there a missing parameter in your dat file? I am not so good with abstract models since I worked principally with `ConcreteModel`s, so I am afraid I can only suggest you to continue working with `ConcreteModel` (BTW, it is way simpler in many cases).

Comment: for example, with the initial value of 100 for model.x, the concrete model can find a optimal solution through pyomo solve command and python script. However, abstract model is only able to solve the model by pyomo solve command.  With the initial value of 10, both concrete and abstract model work fine no matter using command or script.

Comment: For your `AbstractModel`, when setting the value to 100, did you set `model.x=100` or `instance.x=100`? `instance` is in fact a `ConcreteModel` object, so that could help! And for why it works with `10`, more investigation should be done. It could depend on many things. Can you show us where you updated the value of x in your code, while editing your question? Also, it begins to become a different question ("Abstract vs Concrete model?" and "how to know if feasible?"), if you can, I recommend you to open more questions if you have specific issues, so your issues will get better visibility.

Comment: sorry, I must take this issue back because I found one difference between these two models. In my abstract model, I set opt.options["tol"] = 1E-64, then with model.x = Var(model.Crops, model.Inputs, initialize = 100, within=NonNegativeReals) , pyomo says: "Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error". If I manually adjust it into "initialize = 10", pyomo says: "Solved To Acceptable Level". In my concrete model, opt.options has default value, in both cases, concrete model can find optimal solution. I will formulate another question about this and @you.

Comment: This is the link of the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700933/abstractmodel-vs-concretemodel-of-pyomo-how-does-opt-optionstol-make-the