# AbstractModel VS ConcreteModel of pyomo? how does "opt.options["tol"]" make the difference in finding optimal solution?

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

I have an AbstractModel and a ConcreteModel solving the same problem, but they are performing differently. It is mainly about initial value of a variable and tolerance of ipopt.

1. **When I initialize my variable model.x as 10 and opt.options["tol"] = 1E-64:** 
   ConcreteModel can find optimal solution, while abstract model "Solved To Acceptable Level". (But the solutions they find are actually the same)
2. **When I initialize my variable model.x as 100 and opt.options["tol"] = 1E-64:**
   ConcreteModel can find the optimal solution, while abstract model sometimes "Solved To Acceptable Level" and sometimes "Cannot load a SolverResults object with bad status: error".
3. **If I just use the ipopt's default value of the tolerance**, both ConcreteModel and AbstractModel can find the same optimal solution no matter how I initialize the variable model.x.

So I wonder how opt.options["tol"] makes a difference? Why is ConcreteModel always able to find an optimal solution in this case while AbstractModel not?

Variable

```
model.x = Var(model.Crops, model.Inputs, initialize = 100, within=NonNegativeReals)
```

solve script of AbstractModel

```
instance = model.create_instance(data="AbstractCDFarm.dat")
opt = SolverFactory("ipopt")
opt.options["tol"] = 1E-64
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=True) 
instance.display()
```

solve script of ConcreteModel

```
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt.solve(model, tee=True) 
opt.options["tol"] = 1E-64
results = opt.solve
model.display()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling solve twice for the ConcreteModel and it looks like the output you're seeing is for the default Ipopt tolerance not for the tolerance of 1E-64. Why are you setting such a low tolerance? 1E-64 is smaller than machine precision so it's an impossibly small tolerance to converge to.

Comment: No, I have two separated models. Here I just showed the scripts of both models. What exactly does the tolerance value tell us? But you can see that with the low tolerance of 1E-64, the concrete model is still able to find the optimal solution. And why is the abstract model not?

Comment: Double check your scripts. In the script for the ConcreteModel posted in your question you call `opt.solve(model, tee=True)` before setting the solver tolerance. So the output you are seeing on the screen with be with the default Ipopt tolerance of 1E-8. Read about the Ipopt options here: https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node42.html#SECTION000112010000000000000

Comment: I moved the line of tolerance before the line of solve, it also gives "Solved To Acceptable Level". Thanks for your hint!